# Insert method not working Binary Tree java

Tags: java, insert, binary-tree

This is **not** a BinarySearchTree, just a normal binary tree.

Here is my RegularTree class:

```
public class RegularTree extends BinaryTree {

    public RegularTree() {
        super();
    }

    public void insert(Comparable item) {
        if(this.isEmpty()) {
            this.setRoot(new TreeNode(item));
            return;
        }

        TreeNode t = this.getRoot();
        while(t != null) {
            if(t.getLeft() == null)
                t.setLeft(new TreeNode(item));
            else if(t.getRight() == null)
                t.setRight(new TreeNode(item));
            else {
                if(size(t.getLeft()) > size(t.getRight()))
                    t = t.getRight();
                else
                    t = t.getLeft();
            }
        }
    }

    public int size(TreeNode node) {
        return(getSize(node));
    }

    private int getSize(TreeNode node) {
        if (node == null)
            return(0);
        else
            return(getSize(node.getLeft()) + 1 + getSize(node.getRight()));
    }

    public TreeNode find(Comparable key) {
        TreeNode p = this.getRoot();
        while(p != null && key.compareTo(p.getValue()) != 0) {
            if(key.compareTo(p.getValue()) < 0)
                p = p.getLeft();
            else
                p = p.getRight();
        }
        return p;
    }

    public void inorder() {
        doInorderTraversal(this.getRoot());
    }

    private void doInorderTraversal(TreeNode t) {
        if(t != null) {
            doInorderTraversal(t.getLeft());
            System.out.print(t.getValue() + " ");
            doInorderTraversal(t.getRight());
        }
    }

}
```

and here is my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RegularTree tree = new RegularTree();
    tree.setRoot(new TreeNode(1));
    tree.insert(2);
    tree.insert(3);
    tree.insert(4);
    tree.insert(5);
    tree.insert(6);
    tree.inorder();
}
```

This should create a tree that looks like this:

```
                1
              /   \
            2       3
           / \     / 
         4    5   6
```

tree.inorder() should do an inorder traversal of the tree, meaning it should print out 4 2 5 1 6 3

However, when I run my main method nothing happens. I believe there is something wrong with my insert method, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: There might be other issues, but I think that in the insert method you should exit the loop after calling t.set{Left,Right}

Comment: I did as you said, and the tree is inserting now. However, My inorder() method is printing out the following numbers: 4 2 6 1 5 3

For some reason, 5 and 6 are going in the wrong places. I don't think there is a problem with the inorder() method because it worked fine for my BinarySearchTree.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment above, you should return after the call to set{Left,Right}. I have just tested the modification in your code and I got  4 2 5 1 6 3 as you expect.

I did not modify anything else in your code.

I am including the revised version below:

```
public class BinaryTree {

TreeNode root;


public int size(TreeNode node) {
    return(getSize(node));
}

private int getSize(TreeNode node) {
    if (node == null)
        return(0);
    else
        return(getSize(node.getLeft()) + 1 + getSize(node.getRight()));
}

public void insert(Comparable item) {
    if(this.getRoot() == null) {
        this.setRoot(new TreeNode(item));
        return;
    }

    TreeNode t = this.getRoot();
    while(t != null) {
        if(t.getLeft() == null) {
            t.setLeft(new TreeNode(item));
            return;
        }
        else if(t.getRight() == null) {
            t.setRight(new TreeNode(item));
            return;
        }
        else {
            if(size(t.getLeft()) > size(t.getRight()))
                t = t.getRight();
            else
                t = t.getLeft();
        }
    }
}





public TreeNode getRoot() {
    return root;
}

public void setRoot(TreeNode root) {
    this.root = root;
}

public void inorder() {
    doInorderTraversal(this.getRoot());
}

private void doInorderTraversal(TreeNode t) {
    if(t != null) {
        doInorderTraversal(t.getLeft());
        System.out.print(t.getValue() + " ");
        doInorderTraversal(t.getRight());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();
    tree.setRoot(new TreeNode(1));
    tree.insert(2);
    tree.insert(3);
    tree.insert(4);
    tree.insert(6);
    tree.insert(5);
    tree.inorder();

}
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, that is because I have the insert's done incorrectly.
5 should be inserted before 6. For some reason, its switching the places of 5 and 6.

Comment: Why do you think that this is incorrect? Regardless of the order, you still get a binary tree.